# Terminal Closes when I run commands

Tags: gnome-terminal, crash

I open the "terminal" using the link I have on my unity bar.

If I type: `ls -l`

I see files.

If I type: `find` or any other commands, the terminal closes immediately.

This happens after I did an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`

EDIT: must be something else now since Google Chrome and Skype now won't open.

I get:

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome

[3903:3903:0430/105632:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(975)] Failed to create socket directory.
[3903:3903:0430/105632:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1213)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Comment: Can you see any logs for wired behaviour of terminal on /var/log directory ?

Comment: @MiteshShah which log file? I have a lot of them

Comment: Press ctrl+alt+f2 then login in to system and run following command
tail -f /var/log/*

Above command read all the logs file now go back to GUI using ctrl+alt+f7 or f8 and start your terminal when its crash check CLI tail command output

Comment: when I type both true or false, nothing happends, the terminal is still open

Comment: run this command and correct your pesrmissons: `sudo chown -R "$USER":"$USER" "$HOME"` and give me a comment with @A.B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is your program don't have access to write to the temporary folder. `ls` works because it reads the current folder without "saving" anything. `find` on the other hand "caches" data to the temp folder. If he can't it crash!

Check your permissions on the /tmp folder.

`ls -la /tmp`

You should get something like this.

```
bookofzeus@askubuntu:~$ ls -la /tmp
total 60
drwxrwxrwt 12 root    root    12288 May  9 14:39 .
```

Now, check the permissions on the "." It should be writable by everyone.

If not, then that's your problem.

Change it to 1777 (`sudo chmod 1777`)

Comment: no you need to use 1777 to get the sticky bit

Comment: That's not right. I have temporary set my access rigths for `/tmp`: `d--------- 17 root      root      16384 Mai 10 11:38 .` and my terminal works, also with `find`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the `e` option set.

It might have been set in `~/.bashrc`: browse to `~/` with `nautilus` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files, then open `~/.bashrc` with `gedit` and remove this line, if not needed:

```
set -e
```

Comment: I have nothing using the "set" command

Comment: @PatREllery It might have been set somewhere else, run `echo $-` and see if the `e` option is set

Comment: it shows: himBH